# Laravel - Date mutators & format

Tags: laravel

I am trying to understand Dates Mutator in Laravel 7.

My problem : I am developing an API, and I have dates to store sent in format `d/m/Y`

So in my model, I put :

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['type', 'calendar_start', 'calendar_end', 'all_day', 'deleted_at'];

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'calendar_start'  => 'date:d/m/Y',
    'calendar_end' => 'date:d/m/Y',
];
```

Then I want to do : `MyModel::create($request->all());`

Where `calendar_start` & `calendar_end` are dates in format `d/m/Y`

But I have the error :

> Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '01/01/2020' for
>   column 'calendar_start'

So, do I need to format the request ? Is there a way to make it generic ?

Comment: use laravel observer, send the request data to observer then before inserting change the dates value `d/m/Y` to `Y-m-d`

Answer (score 0):

**Date Formats**

By default, timestamps are formatted as **Y-m-d H:i:s**. If you need to customize the timestamp format, set the **$dateFormat property on your model**. This property determines how date attributes are stored in the database, as well as their format when the model is serialized to an array or JSON:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'd/m/Y';
```

You can also use [Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: This doesn't work, it doesn't mutate the incoming date format

Comment: You can also try accessor and mutators. Check here for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62044974/laravel-how-put-a-date-from-order-placed/62045106#62045106