# Laravel : How put a date from order placed

Tags: php, database, laravel, date, foreach

I'm trying to put the date order placed using Carbon.

my-order.blade.php

```
                        @foreach ($order->products as $product)
                            <div>{{ presentDate($order->created_at) }}</div>
                            <div>Total : {{ $product->price }} €</div>
                            <div>Quantity: {{ $product->pivot->quantity }}</div>
                        </div>
```

OrderProduct.php

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

    function presentDate($date)
{
    return Carbon::parse($date)->format('M d, Y');
}
```

Maybe I have to put the function in another place ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why are you calling a function to do that, you can simply format the date directly in the blade as `\Carbon\Carbon::parse($order->created_at)->format('M d, Y')`

Comment: Yes but it's not in the right format, how i can change it ?
It's 2020-05-27 10:12:40 but I want 28-05-2020 10:12:40

Comment: just format it as `\Carbon\Carbon::parse($order->created_at)->format('d-m-Y h:i:s')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage [Laravel Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

In your Model::class

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::parse($date)->format('d-m-Y h:i:s');
}
```

In your blade, you can simply do this

```
<div>{{ $order->created_at }}</div>
```

Comment: as he is trying to retrieve a date in a particular format it should be accessor like `getCreatedAtAttribute($date)`

Comment: @Moshiur Thanks for that. Updated my answer.